# useRef and value at the same time?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an input field component that looks like this:

```
type Props = {
    value?: number;
    onChangeState?: any;
};

const InputField = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, Props>(( onChangeState, value }, ref) => {
        return (
            <>
                <StyledInputField
                    type="number"
                    value={value || 0}
                    ref={ref}
                    onChange={(e) => onChangeState && onChangeState(e.target.valueAsNumber)}
                />
            </>
        );
    }
);

export default InputField;
```

In my other component, where I use it, I do something like this:

```
const MyComponent= () => {
    
    const inputValue = 10
    const inputValueRef = useRef(null);

    return (
        <InputField value={inputValue} ref={inputValueRef} />
    )
}
```

The issue is, when I need to call the `InputField` value with `inputValueRef.current.value`, well, I get that value (in this case predefined as 10, but it could be some other already loaded value). However, if I want to change the value of the `InputField` and use the new value, nothing happens. I can't do backspace, I can't highlight everything and just type in a new value. So basically I am stuck with the predefined value. How can I fix that?

I know I could use `useState`. But I really don't want to re-render everytime a new character is written into the `InputField`. I just want to get the current value of the `InputField` when I click a button, and then show the current value as well, and change it if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're wanting to use your input as an [uncontrolled component](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) (in other words, you want to let the input do its browser-native handling, with your React code merely providing an initial value and reading a value out when done), so you'll need to specify a `defaultValue` instead of a `value`.

However, if by "change it if needed" you mean that you want to be able to *programmatically* change it when needed, that's trickier. You can make it work (via changing React keys to force the component to be recreated, or by ref manipulation), but you're better off using a controlled component at that point.